# regex negative lookahead with named capture group

Tags: regex

I'm having trouble applying a negative lookahead to a named capture group.

I have the below regex and I want to get some results filtered out.

`/^\[.*?(?P<parts>\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}) \] \- "(?P<name>.*?)\.(vol|rar|par|sfv|nfo|nzb)/i`

I want to use a negative lookahead to drop text like `S02E02` so I made a negative lookahead like `(?!S\d{1,2})`, but I'm unable to get it to work within the capture group 'name'

I want the regex to match results like

`[ TrollHD ] - [ 002/124 ] - "2015 Dream Concert 1080p Netflix WEBRip DD+ 2.0 x264-TrollHD.part001.rar" yEnc (1/164)`

but skip results like

`[ TrollHD ] - [ 04/30 ] - "Chelsea S02E05 1080p Netflix WEBRip DD+ 2.0 x264-TrollHD.part03.rar" yEnc (1/164)`

Comment: Try [`^\[.*?(?P<parts>\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}) \] \- "(?!.*S\d{2}E\d{2})(?P<name>.*?)\.(vol|rar|par|sfv|nfo|nzb)`](https://regex101.com/r/Oiq4N9/1)

Comment: That worked, I made an adjustment `/^\[.*?(?P<parts>\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}) \] \- "(?!.*\s((S\d{1,2}E\d{1,3})|(S\d{1,2}))\s)(?P<name>.*?)\.(vol|rar|par|sfv|nfo|nzb)/i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want

```
/^\[.*?(?P<parts>\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}) ] - "(?!.*\sS\d{1,2}(?:E\d{1,3})?\s)(?P<name>.*?)\.(vol|rar|par|sfv|nfo|nzb)/i
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nU2z6n/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?P<parts>\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3})` - A `parts` group, capturing 1 to 3 digits, `/`, 1 to 3 digits
- `] - "` - a  `] - "` -  substring
- `(?!.*\sS\d{1,2}(?:E\d{1,3})?\s)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible followed with a whitespace, `S`, 1 or 2 digits, then - optionally - with `E` and 1 to 3 digits and then a whitesdace (`(?:E\d{1,3})?` is a non-capturing group that is used to match `E` and `\d{1,3}` as a sequence of patterns, and the `?` quantifier makes it match 1 or 
  0 times)
- `(?P<name>.*?)` - Group `name` capturing any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\.` - a `.` char
- `(vol|rar|par|sfv|nfo|nzb)` - any of the values in the alternation group.

Comment: According to regex101 your regex uses 741 steps whereas mine which is a bit longer uses 518. `/^\[.*?(?P<parts>\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3}) \] \- "(?!.*\s((S\d{1,2}E\d{1,2})|(S\d{1,2}))\s)(?P<name>.*?)\.(vol|rar|par|sfv|nfo|nzb)/i`

Comment: @Stephan Probably, you tested against different strings, [here us your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3JUcCf/1) (853 steps) and [here is mine](https://regex101.com/r/nU2z6n/2) (741 steps), tested against the same string. Alternations always lose in efficiency to optional groupings. Anyway, the number of steps does not mean the one regex is more efficient than the other, real efficiency should be tested in the target environment.